# FILE *tmp = tmpfile() always generates NULL pointer in C?

Tags: c, file, buffer

I have the following code:

```
char buffer[8];

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    FILE *input, *output, *tempFile;
    input = fopen(argv[1], "rb");
    if (input == NULL) {
        printf("%s", strerror(2));
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    else {
        output = fopen(argv[2], "wb");
        if (output == NULL) {
            printf("%s", strerror(2));
            exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        }
    }
    tempFile = tmpfile();
    for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
        fputc(buffer[i], tempFile);
        fillBuffer(tempFile);
        printf("%s", buffer);
    }
    if (tempFile == NULL) { 
        printf("Unable to create temp file"); 
        return 0; 
    } 
}
```

Some things have been left out but I believe that this is the relevant portion. The buffer[] array is valid. If in the for loop I use

> fputc(buffer[i], output);

The correct info gets stored in the output file. Whenever I run this program I get a bunch of null results followed by "Unable to create temp file". Advice?

Comment: Please show the function `tmpfile()`.

Comment: @WeatherVane It's there. Right above the for loop.

Comment: Please show the *definition* of function `tmpfile()` (its implementation) because you claim it always returns `NULL`. Also, what is `fillBuffer(tempFile);` supposed to do?

Comment: @WeatherVane I'm sorry, I'm not sure I understand. tmpfile() is a library function and according to my IDE (VS Code), its defined as "FILE *tmpfile(void)".

Comment: Oh - oh! That's a new one for me. I see that it creates a temporary file in the root directory. Do you have permission to do that?

Comment: Also, I see you don't check `if (tempFile == NULL)` until *after* you have been using it. What is its value immediately after being assigned by `tempFile = tmpfile();`?

Comment: @WeatherVane Well considering that the output file is created if its not already present, I assumed that I would have permission to also create a file using tmpfile(). And if not, how would I go about checking whether I have permission?

Comment: I just checked that. It's still NULL.

Comment: @WeatherVane If you can find a way to resolve this, that would be nice. I have tried and failed. At this point I'm just using a workaround where I create a normal file with name "temp" and at the end of the code I use remove("temp"). This works for me and I don't have the energy to try to fix tmpfile();

Comment: The [2019 man page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-runtime-library/reference/tmpfile?view=vs-2019) says *"This example requires **administrative privileges** to run on Windows Vista."* I know Vista is very old but the same perhaps applies. In a recent question using the root folder of C: I was able to view the file from console, but not from Windows File Explorer. It's never a good idea to use a root folder. The man page also says *"To create a temporary file in a directory other than the root, use `tmpnam` or `tempnam` in conjunction with `fopen`."*

Comment: `tmpfile` is absoluely not supposed to create files "in the root folder[sic]". It's supposed to create them in a suitable but unspecified way that actually works. If MSVC's libc is trying to put them in the root directory and can't do that because the user doesn't have permissions, that's a broken implementation.

Comment: Suggest simplifying to `int main(void) { 
    FILE *tempFile = tmpfile(); printf("%lX\n", (unsigned long) tempFile); return 0; 
    }` and report output

Comment: please, read [how to create a minimal, complete and verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) as it is impossible to verify/test your program without an implementation of the `fillBuffer()` function.  Also it would be a good thing if you verify the return code of `tmpfile()` **before using it** and not after.  Consider also that a temporary file is erased after program termination (depending on implementation it is probably erased as soon as it is successfully created, so the system will liberate it's resources when the program exit()s)

Answer (score 1):

The `tmpfile` function is standard C and is supposed to create temporary files in some abstract way the program shouldn't have to care about. If these files even *have* locations (no need for them to) in the filesystem, the location should be one that's suitable for temporary files.

It seems the MSVC implementation of `tmpfile` is buggy and tries to put files in `"C:\"` for h{istor,yster}ical reasons. If you'll be building on MSVC you need to either use a different nonstandard function or drop in a replacement to fix the problem by first creating a file safely in a valid location for temp files, then calling `fopen` on it.

It might be possible to fix this by setting an environment variable, but if it's broken by default that's probably not a suitable fix for a program you want to deploy/ship.

Comment: On MS you should use GetTempFileName and GetTempPath.

Answer (score 0):

I should use:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <errno.h>

int main()
{
    FILE *f = tmpfile();
    if (!f) {
        fprintf(stderr, 
                "couldn't create tmpfile: %s (errno = %d)\n",
                strerror(errno), errno);
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
}
```

in order to know the reason of the failure to create a temporary file.  I've just run it on my system and it creates the file correctly.  (and this should be a [Minimal, Complete and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) as I recommend you to read in my comment to your question)  but most probably had you have done this, you should never have asked this question (as the reason probably is shown in the output of your program).